# how can i create a multidimentianal array that is completely editable in react?

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array

so I am having some trouble creating a multidimensional array that is completely editable. I have static data now set up in a table:

```
export const scores = [
    [0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 7],
    [0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7],
    [0, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7],
];
```

I'm thinking I need to convert it to state, and make the data table static but i'm not sure on what the best approach would be for this. essentually I am looking to make each cell of this table editable and update as the values are entered.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to do a nested loop. On you change handler for each element, may sure to make a copy of both the row and the entire grid so that you don't mutate old state.

The following accomplishes this with buttons for each element, but could be adapted for other input types.

```js
const {useState, Fragment} = React;

const initial = [
    [0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 7],
    [0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7],
    [0, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7],
];

const App = () => {
  const [scores, setScores] = useState(initial);

  return scores.map((row, i) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={i}>
        {row.map((el, j) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={i + "-" + j}
              onClick={() => {
                const rowCopy = [...row];
                rowCopy[j] = el + 1;
                const gridCopy = [...scores];
                gridCopy[i] = rowCopy;
                setScores(gridCopy);
              }}
            >
              {el}
            </button>
          );
        })}
        <br />
      </Fragment>
    );
  });
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```